# shouldn't this have a warning?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, permissions

I am interested to know, why the gcc compiler doesn't throw an error or warning when this code compiles:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int in, out;

    in = open("simpleOpen.c", O_RDONLY);
    out = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);

    while (read(in, &c, 1) == 1)
        write(out, &c,1);

    exit(0);
        }
```

If S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR are part of sys/stat.h why doesn't this get flagged?
I do not see permission settings in the manpages for open, so I'm curious about how to set permissions... should I use sys/stat.h to set permissions, or is the abilty to set permissions in fcntl.h?

Comment: Because GCC does not know about POSIX semantics. You could consider customizing GCC (using your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension) to emit the warning.

Comment: Because other header files may include the needed header files. But it's not something you should depend on, always include the documented header files.

Comment: Also, probably ̀ `S_IRUSER` (etc...) would be defined in some header itself included from one of your `#include`. Compile with `-H` flag to `gcc` to understand which headers are included.

Comment: Compile with `-E` and you'll have a better idea. Or open `fcntl.h`,`unistd.h` and `stdlib.h` and search for `S_IRUSR` or other `#include`

Comment: I have been using gcc -Wall thinking that would list all the warnings. I'll look into other flags.